# IOS Keyboard shifs all clickevents away from their buttons in cordova/ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a really strange behavior in my ionic app. I have a page that looks like a chat page, which has a middle section with messages and a footer section where I can type in my message.

My problem is happening right after the input onBlur event (right after the keyboard have been hidden). The page looks ok, but none of the buttons are responding when touching them. It seems like the keyboard has shifted up all the click events from the buttons. That the click events are not synced with the GUI elements.
If I want to push a button on the screen, I have to tap above the button ( about one "on-screen-keyboard-height" above the button.) And since the back-button is on the top left corner of the screen I cannot push the button, because the click event is of screen.
[image]

Comment: Getting the same behaviour. Did you ever find a solution?